# Shuffling a list while constraining the range of element shift

Tags: arrays, algorithm, range, shuffle

Randomly [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) an array can be easily solved. I want to do a shuffle but with the added restriction that the shift in any element is constrained within a range. So if the max allowed shift `= n`, no element can be moved more than `n` steps in either direction as a result of the shuffle.

So given this array, and n=3:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

this would be a valid shuffle:

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7]
```

while these would be invalid:

```
[2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 0]
```

(notice that the range is not rotational)

We are looking for a simple and efficient way to achieve this. It is preferred to do it in-place, but using a second array is ok if it provides a good solution.

A naive starter solution would be, using a second array:

```
for element in array1:
  get legal index range
  filter out indexes already filled
  select random index i from filtered range
  array20[i] = element
```

**Edit**:

This is regarding the probability distortion issue  raised by @ruakh if the algorithm is to process terminal element(s) first with equal probability:

I thought for a first glance that the probability variance will diminish with increasing array size,
but that doesn't seem to be the case. Some quick tests below  (I concocted this in haste, 
so could have errors). As the distortion in probability is big I don't think it's acceptable 
as a general case, but for my own application I can live with it as I said in the comment.

```
import itertools

n = 2

def test(arlen):
    ar = range(arlen)
    lst = list(itertools.permutations(ar))
    flst = [l for l in lst if not illegal(l)]

    print 'array length', arlen
    print 'total perms: ', len(lst)
    print 'legal perms: ', len(flst)

    frst = [0] * (n+1)
    for l in flst:
        frst[l[0]] +=1

    print 'distribution of first element: ',frst

def illegal(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if abs(l[i]-i)>n: return True

if __name__=="__main__":
    arlen = range(4,10)
    for ln in arlen:
        test(ln)

------------ n=2
array length 4
total perms:  24
legal perms:  14
distribution of first element:  [6, 4, 4]
array length 5
total perms:  120
legal perms:  31
distribution of first element:  [14, 10, 7]
array length 6
total perms:  720
legal perms:  73
distribution of first element:  [31, 24, 18]
array length 7
total perms:  5040
legal perms:  172
distribution of first element:  [73, 55, 44]
array length 8
total perms:  40320
legal perms:  400
distribution of first element:  [172, 128, 100]
array length 9
total perms:  362880
legal perms:  932
distribution of first element:  [400, 300, 232]

------------ n=4
array length 4
total perms:  24
legal perms:  24
distribution of first element:  [6, 6, 6, 6, 0]
array length 5
total perms:  120
legal perms:  120
distribution of first element:  [24, 24, 24, 24, 24]
array length 6
total perms:  720
legal perms:  504
distribution of first element:  [120, 96, 96, 96, 96]
array length 7
total perms:  5040
legal perms:  1902
distribution of first element:  [504, 408, 330, 330, 330]
array length 8
total perms:  40320
legal perms:  6902
distribution of first element:  [1902, 1572, 1296, 1066, 1066]
array length 9
total perms:  362880
legal perms:  25231
distribution of first element:  [6902, 5836, 4916, 4126, 3451]
```

Comment: Do you need all possible resulting arrays to be equally likely? (Note that the probability that `array[0]` ends up `== 0` is not the same as the probability that it ends up `== 1`, etc.)

Comment: @ruakh: in my my particular case, giving up some level of randomness wouldn't hurt, for example between elements processed first and last - if that's what you mean.

Comment: @BaselShishani: Suppose -- for example -- that the array is initially [0,1,2,3], and that n=2 (so we can't end up with [3,...] or [...,0], but everything else is O.K.). Then there are 14 possible resulting arrays, of which 6 start with 0, 4 start with 1, and 4 start with 2. So if we want these 14 possible resulting arrays to all be equally likely, then the 3 possibilities for its first element will *not* all be equally likely. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks, good point. For my own application I can live with such distortion, but as a general solution it won't be acceptable. Also check my edit.

Comment: Please note that, given the arraysize and the max travel-distance, the possible shuffles can be enumerated and/or precalculated.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to see this as an exact-cover problem, and can probably (I didn't test it, but I'll justify this claim) be solved efficiently with a ZDD.

The exact-cover problem will have boolean decision variable for every way every element can be put into the result, so if `n = 0`, there will be as many variables as there are elements, for `n = 1` there will be three variables for every element except the ends, which have two variables each, etc.

If `n` is significantly smaller than the size of the array, that means that decision variables that are "far apart" won't affect each other directly. That should keep the size of the ZDD reasonable, as it is comparable in structure with, for example, tiling problems with small tiles.

edit: actually I'm less sure of this now, especially of the comparability to tiling which seems more and more doubtful, but I still suspect the ZDD will be of manageable size.

On a ZDD of reasonable size, it's possible to efficiently generate a bias-free (ie every solution has equal probability) random solution (which corresponds to a permutation valid under the "don't move more than n places"-rule).

And that's probably not the best way, but it shows it's possible to do it without brute force.

Comment: Thx. Interesting angle. I just want to question that this turns it into an exact cover problem in the traditional sense (NP-complete). The thing is, if we have a priori knowledge about the collection of subsets, then the problem is not an 'exact cover problem'. Say I told you S is the collection of all possible subsets on A, then finding an exact cover/s in S is a trivial problem.

Comment: @BaselShishani well you see I didn't convert exact cover to this problem, but the other way around. So that only proves that it is *at most* as hard as Exact Cover. It's actually easier, of course.

Answer (score 1):

- Input `InputArray`: Array of say integers
- Input `NumberCount`: Number of integers in InputArray
- Input `ShuffleRange`: Valid range a number is allowed to jump
- `ShuffleWindowSize`: Processing window within which swapping happens. Its value is `ShuffleRange +1`
- `ShuffleIndexArray`: Indexes of input numbers in Shuffling Window, Invalid index will be **INT_MIN**

Initialise `ShuffleIndexArray`

> ```
> for (idx =0; idx < ShuffleWindowSize; idx++) {
>   ShuffleIndexArray[idx] = idx;
> }
> ```

Process `InputArray`

```
for (idx = 0; idx < NumberCount; idx++) {

    shuffleIdx = idx % ShuffleWindowSize;

    /* 1. Check if the Element has been moved from it's Original Position
     * 1.1 IF it was swapped already then move to next element
     * 1.2 ELSE perform shuffling within available window
     */
    if (idx != ShuffleIndexArray[shuffleIdx]) { /* was swapped already */
        goto LOOP_CONTINUE;
    }
    /* Get a random Index in the range [0, shuffleWinSize) */
    randomSwapIdx = rand() % shuffleWinSize; /* OffSet */

    /* Skip Invalid Indexes */
    if (INT_MIN == shuffleIndexArray[randomSwapIdx]) {
        for (jdx = randomSwapIdx + shuffleWinSize - 1; jdx > randomSwapIdx; jdx--) {
            if (INT_MIN != shuffleIndexArray[jdx % shuffleWinSize]) {
                randomSwapIdx = jdx % shuffleWinSize;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Get the actual index into InputArray */
    randomSwapIdx = ShuffleIndexArray[randomSwapIdx]; /*Actual Index*/

    /* Check if number gets to stay in original position */
    if (idx == randomSwapIdx) { /* Lucky Bugger */
        goto LOOP_CONTINUE;
    }

    /* Swapping of two numbers in InputArray */
    swapInt = inputArr[idx];
    inputArr[idx] = inputArr[randomSwapIdx];
    inputArr[randomSwapIdx] = swapInt;

    /* Update indexes in Shuffle-Window Array */
    ShuffleIndexArray[randomSwapIdx % ShuffleWindowSize] = idx;

    LOOP_CONTINUE:
    /* InputArray[idx] was processed.
     * Update ShuffleIndexArray */
    ShuffleIndexArray[shuffleIdx] =
            ((idx + ShuffleWindowSize) < NumberCount) ?
                    (idx + ShuffleWindowSize) : INT_MIN;
}
```

It's an in-place shuffling except we need another array of size `ShuffleWindowSize` to keep track of indexes.

Comment: Would be nicer if you provided few lines explaining what this does in crude pseudo code, easier for the reader than going through couple pages of c trying to discern the concept. Cheers.

Comment: @BaselShishani Hope it's easier now.

Comment: Ok, in my words: you're sliding a window of size n+1 over the array, at each slide step, take the first element in the window, if it has not been swapped before, swap it with a random element from the rest of the window. You're also imposing that the latter element has not been swapped before, if it has, just find the first unswapped element from the rest of window and use that for swapping with first element. Correct?

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea actually. Not quite sure but one of the following might improve on it: either don't check the latter element for being swapped as it can't get out of range, or select the first unswapped element starting from the random element (and rotating). Also to mention it won't be completely bias free as said about others.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re not too picky about having an equal probability for each possible output. One simple solution might be to do the equivalent of `n` passes of bubble sort, but rather than sorting the elements, just randomly choose whether or not to exchange the two elements at each step. This approach lets you do the randomization in place, too. You could do something like:

```
import random
def shuffle_list(list, n):
    for ipass in xrange(n):
        for ielt in xrange(len(list) - 1):
            if random.randrange(2):
                temp = list[ielt]
                list[ielt] = list[ielt + 1]
                list[ielt + 1] = temp
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I should have thought about this more. The approach I described doesn’t work — in the very first pass, there’s a nonzero probability of the first element bubbling all the way to the end of the list. Somehow I missed that.

I guess I don’t really have an answer now, but here’s an idea at least: Assign each element in the original list a proxy value equal to `ii + random.uniform(-n/2., n/2.)`, where `ii` is the element's index in the original list; then sort the original list based on this proxy value. Then, the earliest that element `ii` can appear in the final list is position `ii-n`: this would only happen if element received proxy value `ii-n/2.` and each element starting with element `ii-n` received a proxy value of at least `ii-n/2.`. Same argument for the upper bound.

In practice, you’d want to use a slightly wider range, probably something like `random.uniform(-n/2. - 0.49, n/2. + 0.5)`. I haven’t gone through this math carefully yet, but I think this maintains the distance constraint. I’m also not totally sure what the final distribution of possible lists will be. @Basel, I think you’re right about the original suggestion, it seems more likely to have each element move a small amount rather than a large amount. I think this solution should be better, but I can’t swear to that. :-)

Comment: Thx. Ok this provides some perturbation, but I can see with this that it's harder to throw an element further away within the range. i.e there's a probability distribution around an element where prob(s+1) [s:steps] is less than prob(s) [half?!]. This is imposing an extra restriction beyond the original question, where a local shuffle would by definition assign equal probabilities within the local range.

Comment: I'm trying to say that here bias is built in rather than being a trade-off. Also, because of the bias is significant, it would limit the shuffle effect.

Comment: The fluctuating proxy index idea seems to work, as it can't throw an element out of range. I can think of one mod where if two indexes have equal values they can be swapped with a 50/50 chance. (I'll put it in code and test it properly soon). (WRT the first proposal, it can be worked by skipping an element if it'd been swapped already, but the central bias issue we talked about would still shoot it down).